# Android Broadcast Receiver bluetooth events catching

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-broadcast, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to catch bluetooth state changes with Broadcast Receiver.

My manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<application>
     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".BluetoothBroadcastReceiver"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Receiver `onReceive` method:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d("BroadcastActions", "Action "+action+"received");
    int state;
    BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;

    switch(action)
    {
        case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED:
            state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1);
            if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("BroadcastActions", "Bluetooth is off");
            }
            else if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth is turning off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("BroadcastActions", "Bluetooth is turning off");
            }
            else if(state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON)
            {
                Log.d("BroadcastActions", "Bluetooth is on");
            }
            break;

        case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED:
            bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Connected to "+bluetoothDevice.getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("BroadcastActions", "Connected to "+bluetoothDevice.getName());
            break;

        case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED:
            bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Disconnected from "+bluetoothDevice.getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

I launch app then minimize it by pressing Home button. Go to settings and turn on bluetooth but nothing happens. Though I expect toast and logcat messages. What's wrong here?

Comment: Not sure, it may be because of the way broadcast registered. I would try to register in service instead at runtime and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @VladimirLichonos Yep, I've tried to add service where I register receiver. It looked like this `IntentFilter fltr = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
        fltr.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
        fltr.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        fltr.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(brecv, fltr);` where `brecv` is an object of CustomBluetoothReceiver. There were no any changes.

Comment: Do you start the Service in some place ?

Comment: Thanks. That was an emulator problem. On real device it works fine.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In order to catch Bluetooth state changes (`STATE_OFF`, `STATE_TURNING_ON`, `STATE_ON`, `STATE_TURNING_OFF`), do this:

First, add Bluetooth permission to your AndroidManifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Create a BroadcastReceiver in your Activity or Service:

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch(state) {
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    ..
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                    ..
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                    ..
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                    ..
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Create an IntentFilter and register it with BroadcastReceiver in your Activity/Service's `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, filter1);
    
    ...
}
```

Unregister BroadcastReceiver in your `onDestroy()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1);
}
```

In order to catch changes of discoverability of device (`SCAN_MODE_NONE`, `SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE`, `SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE`), create another BroadcastReceiver and register/unregister to your Activity as I mentioned above. Only difference between those BroadcastReceivers is the first one uses `BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE` and the other one uses `BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE`. Here is the example code for BroadcastReceiver to catch discoverability changes:

Create an IntentFilter and register it in `onCreate()` method:

```
IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter();
filter2.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
filter2.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
filter2.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2, filter2);
```

Create the BroadcastReciver in Activity/Service to catch discoverability changes:

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)) {

            int mode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch(mode){
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:
                    ..
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:
                    ..
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                    ..
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And lastly unregister BroadcastReciver in `onDestroy()`:

```
unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2);
```

Note that, you don't need to add any `<intent-filter>` or `<receiver>` to your AndroidManifest file, except you need to add Bluetooth permission of course.

If you want to catch (`ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED`, `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED`, `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED`), now you need to add an `<intent-filter>` to your AndroidManifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Create filter and register it in `onCreate()` method:

```
IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter();
filter3.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
filter3.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, filter3);
```

Then create the BroadcastReceiver in your Activity/Service:

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        switch (action){
            case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED:
                ..
                break;
            case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED:
                ..
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

And lastly, unregister:

```
unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3);
```

If you want to read more about state constants, this is from the documentation:

> [public static final String EXTRA_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#EXTRA_STATE):
>
> Used as an int extra field in ACTION_STATE_CHANGED intents to request
> the current power state. Possible values are: STATE_OFF,
> STATE_TURNING_ON, STATE_ON, STATE_TURNING_OFF
>
> [public static final String EXTRA_SCAN_MODE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#EXTRA_SCAN_MODE):
>
> Used as an int extra field in ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED intents to
> request the current scan mode. Possible values are: SCAN_MODE_NONE,
> SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE, SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE

Comment: I want to use Connect Disconnect broadcasts in my application I have same code but I am registering broadcasts in Manifest itself. Problem is I am receiving broadcast randomly for random devices..I am using Android M(6.0)  I am receiving broadcast just after pairing to device also and sometimes without pairing also and that too though device is not in pairing mode then also.Can you please help me?

Comment: Did something change in Oreo? This doesn't seem to fire anymore

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#receiving_broadcasts: "Beginning with Android 8.0 (API level 26), the system imposes additional restrictions on manifest-declared receivers. If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for most implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically)."

Comment: This answer is just beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: @TobiasUhmann But `ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` (among others) are [exempt](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html) from that restriction.

Comment: Is there a way to test Bluetooth related events on the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to replicate the same but not able to achieve success in this regard.

This is my class file

```
class BluetoothCheckActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val bluetoothBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val action: String? = intent?.action
        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            val state: Int? =
                intent?.getIntExtra(
                    BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                    BluetoothAdapter.ERROR
                )
            when (state) {
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON -> tv_bluetoothCheck.text = "Bluetooth is On"
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON -> tv_bluetoothCheck.text =
                    "Bluetooth is Turning ON"
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF -> tv_bluetoothCheck.text =
                    "Bluetooth is Off"
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF -> tv_bluetoothCheck.text =
                    "Bluetooth is Turning Off"
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth_check)
    val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
    try {
        registerReceiver(bluetoothBroadcastReceiver, filter)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
override fun onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(bluetoothBroadcastReceiver)
    super.onDestroy()
}}
```

Comment: not working for me too, any solution?

Comment: Nope, still searching a solution.

Comment: i hope we find one