# On Android, can I register for a callback that tells me if Bluetooth is turned on or off?

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth, android-lifecycle

I need to know inside my app whether bluetooth is on or off. Or if bluetooth was turned on or off e.g. from the OS settings pulldown menu. I thought I could do this in the Activity's `onResume()`. But it turns out that the activity is not paused when the Android OS's settings "pulldown menu" (the one that is accessed by pulling down with a finger from the top edge of the screen) is opened.

I need to update my UI when bluetooth becomes available or unavailable.

Can I register for a callback (e.g. a `BroadcastReceiver`) or any other callback to let the system tell me when Bluetooth availability changes?

Comment: You can find a complete solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222409/android-broadcast-receiver-bluetooth-events-catching)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can register the receiver with intent filter:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.example.BluetoothReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And this is the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1);

            switch (state){
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    //Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is off.
                break;

                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                    //Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is turning on. However local clients should wait for STATE_ON before attempting to use the adapter.
                break;

                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                    //Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is on, and ready for use.
                break;

                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                    //Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is turning off. Local clients should immediately attempt graceful disconnection of any remote links.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Or if you want to add directly in the activity:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1);

                switch (state) {
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        //Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is off.
                        break;

                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        //Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is turning on. However local clients should wait for STATE_ON before attempting to use the adapter.
                        break;

                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        //Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is on, and ready for use.
                        break;

                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        //Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is turning off. Local clients should immediately attempt graceful disconnection of any remote links.
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: for completeness, how to add this to an activity?

Comment: @treesAreEverywhere I just updated my answer with the example of `BroadcastReceiver` added directly in the `Activity`

Comment: worked for me. The other option I was going for was to lengthy!!!
But this one is a savior.

Answer (score 4):

This is the intent-filter you need:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>
</intent-filter>
```