# isMultipleAdvertisementSupported() returning false

Tags: android, bluetooth, ads, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon-android

If i check this

```
bluetoothadapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported();
```

with my Bluetooth disable, it returns false... and if is enable, it returns true.

What i am trying to do is that if the bluetooth is disable, enable it (i do this programaticaly and is working fine) and then check for isMultipleAdvertisementSupported(), but when i do this, it returns false instead of true. It seems i have to wait a little bit until bluetooth is fully enabled. Do i have a listener or callback for this? what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen the same on several device models where `isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()` returns false for a few seconds after bluetooth power-on.

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` to be called on  `<action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>`, but I have not tried to see if the `isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()` consistently returns true after you get the callback with `BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON`.

You can see details on how to set this up here: [On Android, can I register for a callback that tells me if Bluetooth is turned on or off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260292/on-android-can-i-register-for-a-callback-that-tells-me-if-bluetooth-is-turned-o)

If you try this, please comment on whether this gives you consistent results with `isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()` post-callback.