# BroadcastReceiver on android received Byte

Tags: android, android-studio, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to do `BroadcastReceiver`  class  and implementation of some commands I  implemented class  but and not  found the  filter  to make  `onReceived` method work only  when received data via Bluetooth

How can I do the filter that allow to `onReceived` method work only when received data via Bluetooth?

Comment: you can add a filter in the androidmanifest.xml file...you should also probably follow this questions answer step by step to implement a broadcast receiver http://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/3731795

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Broadcast Receiver bluetooth events catching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222409/android-broadcast-receiver-bluetooth-events-catching)

Comment: Please  understand  me , I just want  filter  who used to work function 'onreceived'  work   only when  android phone receive  Bytes  via  Bluetooth  @penduDev

Comment: This does not work when receiving data  @RajenRaiyarela

Comment: can you also put relevant bits of code in this question for better understanding?

Comment: a common mistake people make is using LocalBroadcastReceiver instead of using a global BroadcastReceiver...you can google about it