# connect to a bluetooth module android

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I'm developing an app that has to connect to a Bluetooth module like this:
http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/RN42

This Bluetooth module is located on an electronic board.

My app is able to connect with the chip and it communicates correctly (send and receive data).

But, I have a doubt. In some cases, it seems that my app loses the communication with the chip, and so I thought: maybe I'm wrong the method of connection between app and chip.

I follow the guide here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html
and my app works like client, so the code is the code of "Connecting as a client" section of the page. I also use, like UUID, "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB".

The question is: the connection method is correct? The UUID is correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a BroadcastReceiver to check if your phone is really disconnecting sometimes. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222409/android-broadcast-receiver-bluetooth-events-catching).